# Finding missing values for which I already have data in R

Tags: r

I am working with a big data set. The data was entered by different people and it has been a little bit of a mess.

Our data looks like this...

```
Name     Brothers   Sisters   Children
John        2           1         2
James       1           0         1
Joshua      4           1         4 
James       0           0         0 
John        2           1         NA
Willian     1           1         1
Peter       2           2         0 
James       1           0         NA 
Micahel     2           1         2
```

Some of the names are repeated. However, sometimes there is an NA in the column of children when they are supposed to have data. With this example it would be very easy to fix, but we estimate that it can be happening with at least 200. So, my question is:

*Is there a way to search for how many NA's we have data? and it would be even better if it can take the data from the other one.*

But at least I want to know how many or create a list of the ones that are missing so we can fix this error.

Thanks.

Comment: This will show the indices of NA values: `which(is.na(df$Children)==TRUE)` . You can use `length(which(is.na(df$Children)==TRUE))` to find how many NAs are in your data.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do. You can select all missing rows with `data[ is.na( data[["Children"]] ), ]`

Comment: can other columns be missing? if so this solution would work too : `df[!complete.cases(df),]`

Comment: Is not only the missing values that I want to check. Is the ones that are "missing" but I already have data. Like in the example, John - John/ James-James

Comment: @ahmathelte `==TRUE` is redundant there. You can just say `which(is.na(df$Children))`

Comment: Can we assume that 1) the rows with the same name repeat at most once; 2) one of them has `NA` in column `children`?

Comment: Are duplicate rows desirable? Is there any chance that non-missing values given for the same name might conflict with one another?

Comment: @RuiBarradas No, there are some rows that are repeated and contain the correct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fill()` from `tidyr` to fill in missing values by group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Name     Brothers   Sisters   Children
John        2           1         2
James       1           0         1
Joshua      4           1         4 
James       0           0         0 
John        2           1         NA
Willian     1           1         1
Peter       2           2         0 
James       1           0         NA 
Micahel     2           1         2
", header = TRUE)


df2 <- df1 |> 
      group_by(Name) |> 
      fill(Children)
```

Comment: @ Mike This is it. You just saved me hours of work. This function is great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

In base R, just the indices.

```
which(is.na(df1$Children))
#[1] 5 8
```

---

A `dplyr` way to keep the rows with `NA`'s.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(is.na(Children))
## A tibble: 2 x 4
## Groups:   Name [2]
#  Name  Brothers Sisters Children
#  <chr>    <int>   <int>    <int>
#1 John         2       1       NA
#2 James        1       0       NA
```

A `dplyr` way to count for how many `NA`'s there is data. From the question:

> Is there a way to search for how many NA's we have data? And it would be even better if it can take the data from the other one.

```
df1 %>%
  filter(is.na(Children)) %>%
  count(Name, name = 'NA')
#   Name NA
#1 James  1
#2  John  1
```

---

A `data.table` solution.

Just the indices.

```
dt1[, .I[is.na(Children)], by = Name]$V1
#[1] 5 8
```

Keep the rows with `NA`'s.

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
dt1[dt1[, .I[is.na(Children)], by = Name]$V1, ]
#    Name Brothers Sisters Children
#1:  John        2       1       NA
#2: James        1       0       NA
```

And count the rows with `NA`'s for which there are data.

```
dt1[dt1[, .I[is.na(Children)], by = Name]$V1, .('NA' = sum(is.na(.SD))), by = Name]
#    Name NA
#1:  John  1
#2: James  1
```

---

### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Name     Brothers   Sisters   Children
John        2           1         2
James       1           0         1
Joshua      4           1         4 
James       0           0         0 
John        2           1         NA
Willian     1           1         1
Peter       2           2         0 
James       1           0         NA 
Micahel     2           1         2
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: This appears to delete the rows that contain the NA's. I don't want to delete them. I just need to fill them with the correct values.

Comment: @Ajrhmamd OK, see now.